# parse json using php(object inside object)

Tags: php, api, rest, linkedin-api

Below is the example json code i am trying to parse using php.

```
{
    "educations": {
        "_total": 7
    }
}
```

I tried it parsing using the following php code. But i am making some silly mistake which i am unable to find. Below is the PHP code

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode($json_string)
echo "$decoded->educations->_total";

?>
```

but I am not getting some object error which i am unable to figure out.

The error is:
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

PLease help thanks.

Comment: So what is that object error?

Comment: i have updated the question please check

Comment: Is that the actual $json_string value, i.e. before you use json_decode()? e.g. the result of a var_dump()? If so, then there's an extra ','

Comment: I just want to know how to parse a associate array which was converted by using json_decode. Condition is i want to parse object inside object

Comment: Well if you remove that spurious comma, it works, http://ideone.com/Mj9hsg

Comment: my mistake I added a double quote which messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry My silly mistake:

```
$total= "$decoded->educations->_total";
```

I added a double quote which created this problem. The below code is the correct one.

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode($json_string)
echo $decoded->educations->_total;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your returned json object as an array

```
$total = $decoded['educations']['_total'];
```